# Django ajax search not returning result but the url prints in console

Tags: django, ajax

I am developing a Django Ajax search that searches through a list of college courses. After I finished implementing, I realized that the search doesn't work. However, my shell prints out the updated URL. Here is what I mean.

If I search for BUS, My console would do this, but my HTML file wouldn't change:

Note: If it's easier, I can add a GitHub link to my code

**UPDATE: Github [link](https://github.com/abhivemp/smore)**

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 13, 2020 - 11:37:25
Django version 3.0, using settings 'smore.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[13/Aug/2020 11:37:28] "GET /courses/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19376
Not Found: /artists/
[13/Aug/2020 11:37:35] "GET /artists/?q=BUS HTTP/1.1" 404 2092
```

I can't seem to understand where the `/artists/` is coming from. I changed the endpoints and the URLs respectively. Here are my files

### urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from search import views as v

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('courses/', v.course_view, name = "courses")
]
```

### settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = blahblahblah

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'search.apps.SearchConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'smore.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'smore.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/search/"), # for the css file
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import collegeCourse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse
# Create your views here.
# core/views.py
def course_view(request):
    ctx = {}
    url_param = request.GET.get("q")

    if url_param:
        courses = collegeCourse.objects.filter(course_code__icontains=url_param)
    else:
        courses = collegeCourse.objects.all()

    ctx["courses"] = courses

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string(
            template_name="partial-courses.html",
            context={"courses": courses}
        )

        data_dict = {"html_from_view": html}

        return JsonResponse(data=data_dict, safe=False)

    return render(request, "courses.html", context=ctx)
```

### Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Search | Courses</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap-->

    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JQuery -->

    <script src="{% static 'javascript/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <link href="{% static "main.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}
    </div>



    {% block footer %}
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "javascript/main.js" %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

### courses.html

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Courses</h3>

<div class="row">

  {# icon and search-box #}
  <div class="col-6 align-left">
    <i id="search-icon" class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <input id="user-input" placeholder="Search">
  </div>

  {# course section #}
  <div id="replaceable-content" class="col-6">
    {% include 'partial-courses.html' %}
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

### partial-courses.html

```
{# partial-courses.html #}
{% if courses %}
  <ul>
  {% for course in courses %}
    <li>{{ course.course_code }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>No course found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

### Main.js

```
const user_input = $("#user-input")
const search_icon = $('#search-icon')
const courses_div = $('#replaceable-content')
const endpoint = '/courses/'
const delay_by_in_ms = 700
let scheduled_function = false

let ajax_call = function (endpoint, request_parameters) {
    $.getJSON(endpoint, request_parameters)
        .done(response => {
            // fade out the courses_div, then:
            courses_div.fadeTo('slow', 0).promise().then(() => {
                // replace the HTML contents
                courses_div.html(response['html_from_view'])
                // fade-in the div with new contents
                courses_div.fadeTo('slow', 1)
                // stop animating search icon
                search_icon.removeClass('blink')
            })
        })
}


user_input.on('keyup', function () {

    const request_parameters = {
        q: $(this).val() // value of user_input: the HTML element with ID user-input
    }

    // start animating the search icon with the CSS class
    search_icon.addClass('blink')

    // if scheduled_function is NOT false, cancel the execution of the function
    if (scheduled_function) {
        clearTimeout(scheduled_function)
    }

    // setTimeout returns the ID of the function to be executed
    scheduled_function = setTimeout(ajax_call, delay_by_in_ms, endpoint, request_parameters)
})
```

Comment: You don't have a url handler for /artists/. You're going to have to do a global search across your project to see what function is trying to navigate there.

Comment: Yeah I did that already. Looked at every file searching for the word 'artist' but I didn't seem find anything. I was learning about this through this [tutorial](https://openfolder.sh/django-tutorial-as-you-type-search-with-ajax)

Comment: That tutorial uses `/artist`.  I do not have the ability to search your project.  perhaps you are in the wrong directory?

Comment: Is it easier, if I link my repository with the code? And I believe I put my files in the right place.

Comment: @GAEfan I have linked my code in the question

Comment: cd into the `smore` directory and then start.

Comment: @GAEfan could you clarify? What do you mean cd into `smore`? I would have to do that to runserver

Comment: I think you are running this from the directory that contains your project, not from the project itself.  Change directory (cd) into the smore folder, then start the project.

Comment: You must be saying that because my pip files are outside the project folder? Also, even if I change the place where I am running the project, how would that fix the artists URL?

Comment: I think you are picking up that URL from a `urls.py` in another project, like the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a blunder error. But I didn't properly import my model. Instead of `from .models import whatever`, I needed to do `from appname.models import whatever`